# Does Swedish "varje" have both distributive and collective readings?

Tags: semantics, swedish, quantifiers

"Varje" is often translated as "each" or "every" in English. However, "each" and "every"  have different uses in regard to collectivity/distributivity. It is my understanding that "varje" takes a distributive reading, but I am not sure if collective readings are also possible. I have some sentences below to try to test this. I am not a native Swedish speaker, so I need some help from those who are.

**1) Varje elev samlades i korridoren.**

Imagine we have a group of 10 students. If "varje" is strictly distributive, then I imagine 1) should sound odd, since each student cannot gather him/herself. Or, is it possible to interpret "varje" collectively (i.e., the group of students)?

**2) Varje lamm väger circa 150 kg.**

Imagine we have 5 lambs. If "varje" is strictly distributive, I imagine that this forces us to believe that each individual lamb weighs 150kg. But, is it also possible to interpret this collectively? For example, say I put 500kg instead of 150kg (to make it plausible), can it be possible that the group of lambs (sum of their weights) collectively weighs 500kg?

Thanks!

Comment: I’m not a native speaker either, though a fairly competent one, and the first one does sound odd to me. _Varje elev gick ut i korridoren_ is very natural, but _varje elev samlades_ isn’t. In the second example, it is definitely **not** possible to understand the 150 kg as referring to the combined weight of the sheep. It’s quite unambiguously each individual sheep that weighs 150 kg. But this is true of both _each_ and _every_ in English as well (‘each/every student gathered in the corridor’ doesn’t work either). I’d say _varje_ is as distributive as _each_ in English.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! If you replace the 150kg with 500kg, can you receive the collective reading (i.e., total weight of 5 lambs = 500kg)?

Comment: Nope, doesn’t matter what the weight is. If it’s 5 kg, then each/every lamb weighs 5 kg (25 kg in total); if it’s 500 kg, then you’ve got two and a half tonnes worth of the world’s most ginormous lambs. (Incidentally, I would say 150 kg for five lambs sounds more reasonable than 100 kg per lamb, but I’m no farmer, and I don’t make a habit of carrying lambs around.)

Comment: @dj1121 I'm not sure I get this about lambs... you can't say "Every lamb weighs 500kg" in English and mean that they weight 500kg in total, and you *say* can't say "Each lamb weighs 500kg" and mean that. It doesn't matter which of "every" or "each" you use, it just doesn't work, so I wouldn't expect to work it in Swedish no matter which English word it best matches.

Comment: @LjL Generally speaking, _every_ is less insistent on being distributive than _each_ in English, allowing collective uses in some cases, though the lamb example doesn’t really show it. The first example does, though: “*Each student gathered in the corridor” is unequivocally impossible, whereas “?Every student gathered in the corridor” is at least marginally possible. A better example would be that “Every student was photographed” would still be true if they were photographed in groups, whereas “Each student was photographed” requires that it’s one by one. _Varje_ could be both in that case.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for the example with the photograph. I think that is a better example of the collectivity of "every" that I had in mind! I think the lamb example is perhaps more negligible, depending on the English speaker. Good to know that Varje can be both dist./collec. in that photo case.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet yes, I understand that there *is* a difference, and wasn't trying to imply the two English words are interchangeable; I'm just saying that in the example given with the lambs, neither word will work in English, and so I don't see how the example applies to Swedish, no matter which English word "varje" is closer to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct about both sentences. The first one, *Varje elev samlades i korridoren*, not only sounds odd but is something that no one would say. (One would expect *Alla eleverna samlades…*.)

Your understanding of the second sentence, *Varje lamm väger cirka 150 kg*, is also spot-on: it can only mean that each of the lambs weighs about 150 kg (although I doubt a lamb that heavy has ever existed).

*Note:* In Swedish the spelling is *cirka*, not *circa*.

I also seem to remember that grammar textbooks refer to *varje* as a purely distributive pronoun.

(My credentials for this: Native speaker who grew up in Sweden and who visits and does work there every year. Not living there at present.)

Comment: Thank you very much!